I am not able to specify network in brownie run
I am not able to specify networks in brownie run.
brownie run ./scripts/deployment_v2.py --network ropsten
I get error
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
error log:
PS C:\Users\ADMIN\Polygon-flashloan-arb-bot> brownie run ./scripts/deployment_v2.py --network ropsten
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.20.5 - Python development framework for Ethereum
PolygonFlashloanArbBotProject is the active project.
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\Lib\site-packages\brownie_cli_main_.py", line 62, in main
importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\Lib\site-packages\brownie_cli\run.py", line 45, in main
network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\Lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py", line 31, in connect    active = CONFIG.set_active_network(network)
File "C:\Users\ADMIN\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\Lib\site-packages\brownie_config.py", line 78, in set_active_network
network["settings"] = self.settings["networks"][key].copy()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
I am not able to specify network in brownie run.
thanks
Uday
